# Cómo graficar fractales en java

Tags: java

¿Cómo hago para graficar el **Fractal de Lorenz** usando java Swing y AWT?
Éstas son las fórmulas:

```
double a = 10.0;
double b = 28.0;
double c = 8/3;
double dt =0.01;
double dx = (a * (y - x)) * dt;
double dy = (x * (b - z) - y) * dt;
double dz = (x * y - c * z) * dt;
x = x + dx;
y = y + dy;
z = z + dz;
```

Comment: Dibuja los puntos `x`, `y` y `z` utilizando alguna librería como [jogl](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) o mejor en Java FX que es el sucesor de los antiquísimos AWT y Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facil. Usa la clase `TimerTask`: en la cual podrás iterar cada **dt** unidades de tiempo.

```
double a = 10.0;
double b = 28.0;
double c = 8/3;
double dt =0.01;
double dx = 0;
double dy = 0;
double dz = 0;

Timer temporizer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Actualiza diferenciales
        dx = (a * (y - x)) * dt;
        dy = (x * (b - z) - y) * dt;
        dz = (x * y - c * z) * dt;

        // Actualiza el valor de las coordenadas x, y, z
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        z = z + dz;

        // Dibujarlas en algún canvas para mostrarlas en la UI
        ...

    }
};
temporizer.schedule (task,0,100);
```

Y verás como hermosamente se van graficando  las curvas cada dt tiempo.

Puedes ver como hice una simulación similar en este repositorio https://github.com/hcarrasc/SHM-simulator/